# ASP.NET/MVC 3 Status

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the status of ASP.NET/MVC technology? Would there be big changes that affect every code base? Is it stable (backward compatible) enough to be used in real world?

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "backward compatible"? To what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You know, the very site you're using.. Stack Overflow, was written in MVC.  That should answer your question.

Comment: Using just the MVC pattern (with home-grown tools) or using ASP.NET/MVC?

Comment: It is using 100% ASP.NET MVC with linq to sql. I think they're up to using ASP.NET MVC2, but not sure about that one.

Comment: @Gats @Kaveh actually we (stackoverflow) currently use ASP.NET MVC3, and we mix our LINQ-to-SQL with some of our custom micro-ORM, [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). And our MVC3 upgrade was entirely pain free, except for the changes we *decided* to make in order to use MVC3 features (razor, in particular)

Comment: Ah thanks Marc!! I've fallen behind since reading up early. Thanks to all of you for your wonderful work, both in being pragmatic (rather than overengineered) in initial build and scaling with your audience. It's a long overdue case study for a startup succeeding in .net :) We always knew it was possible.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is stable. Yes, it is production ready. It is used on this very same site. Depending on your existing *code base* there might or might not be big changes in order to port it to ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: When I said "backward compatible" I mean between different versions of MVC itself. For example is there any plans to add breaking changes in ASP.NET/MVC 4? Because there was in 2 and 3. Thanks

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian, ASP.NET MVC 4 is still not announced, neither any possible new features. So until the first preview is announced we cannot know whether there will be breaking changes or not.

Comment: There are always breaking changes between versions of frameworks.  The .NET framework always has a list of them.  Sometimes new features are added that require some changes. and sometimes features that were added in previous releases didn't work out very well and need to be changed.

Answer (score 3):

Kaveh, I banned using MVC1 in my team because I am a late adopter but a fast adopter (agency work doesn't have time for discovering bugs on behalf of the creator).

Since MVC2 (and now including MVC3), I am very very keen for people to use it. There are some things about MVC that might be difficult if you've only ever worked in web forms, but if you understand http, and html, then it has cut away a lot of the annoying bulk in web forms.

- MVC will quickly overtake Webforms in popularity.
- MVC
  requires less code in most cases.
- MVC enables very easy integration
  with other client side frameworks and now defaults to using jquery as a standard (in webforms, lightweight ajax usually requried a lot of custom code and quite a bit of repetition).
- MVC generates almost no
  garbage in your html output.
- MVC is
  long overdue, stable, secure and simply a
  fantastic step in the right direction
  for Microsoft.

I would only suggest you tread carefully with where you get your advice on how to do things and any use of 3rd party products like StructureMap that are not supported by Microsoft. I have seen some people make big mistakes with that combination, but never because of MVC.

There was little or no breaking changes from MVC2 - MVC3 unless you'd used certain approaches. I would actually say you are less likely to get breaking changes in future but any version upgrade in any platform will require some work if the changes are worth it.

Comment: curious about the kinds of mistakes you are talking about with StructureMap.

Comment: Seen a few shockers. Mainly bootstrapping badly and losing thread safety.. was very difficult to spot in testing too. I don't see what's so elusive about DI and strong believer in writing your own as needed, even if it takes a few weekends to understand it. If how you are getting DI in your app is outside your own understanding then there's trouble... totally know that's not the standard opinion these days, but it's mine :)